# C++ thread with returning value from a function

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have one function `myf` taking ranges of processor numbers as an argument and returns `true`. And the number of `true` values should be equal to the total number of processors available to the system. But, when I am running this program I am always getting less number of true values than the processor numbers.

Can someone please help me to figure out this problem?

#### Prototype example is shown here:

```
// Header
bool myf(int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    uint data_size = 9260; // Number of data points, here is an arbitrary large number.
    int startIndex, endIndex; // Processor index.
    int ncpus = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN); // Get number of processors.
    int PerCPU = data_size / ncpus; // Data points per CPU.

    std::thread t[ncpus];
    vector<bool> test(ncpus, false); // Variable to collect return values from the myf.

    for(int icpu = 0; icpu < ncpus; icpu++)
    {
        startIndex = icpu * PerCPU;
        endIndex = startIndex + PerCPU;

        if(((uint) endIndex > data_size)
            || ((icpu == ncpus - 1) && ((uint) endIndex < data_size)))
            endIndex = data_size;

        // Evaluate function value at each thread.
        t[icpu] = std::thread([&] { test[icpu] = myf(startIndex, endIndex); });
    }

    // Join all threads.
    for(int icpu = 0; icpu < ncpus; icpu++)
    {
        t[icpu].join();
    }

    // Count output from all the threads.
    uint bool_size=0;
    for(uint icpu = 0; icpu < test.size(); icpu++)
    {
        bool_size += test[icpu];
    }

    // Output should be 64, if ncpus = 64.
    cout << " bool_size :: " << bool_size << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

#### Compilation procedure:

> g++ main.cpp -pthread -std=c++0x

Comment: If you're using C++11 you may want to see feature like `future`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/

Comment: Can you read your own code?

Comment: Hi, Kanaev thanks for your suggestion, but I would like to know what is the problem with is this code ?Am I doing anything stupid ?

Comment: @musafir Not stupid, but the code is very hard to read. Don't copy-paste whole code block but only sufficient part of.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you describe is caused by the asynchronous execution of threads in relation to the increase of the index counter in the main thread loop.

```
for(int icpu = 0; icpu < ncpus; icpu++) {
    /* ... */
    t[icpu] = std::thread([&] { test[icpu] = myf(startIndex, endIndex); });
}
```

Here, each thread is passed a lambda which captures all objects it employs by **reference** (including the index counter `icpu`). Hence, the asynchronous execution of the thread<sup>†</sup> causes the read of the index to be out of sync with the increments, *i.e.*, the index might have been incremented already when the thread reads it. And because of this, the value of `true` is sometimes stored at the wrong index in the vector `test`.

Furthermore, this is undefined behaviour as reading and writing to the same memory (`icpu`) at the same time concurrently causes a *data race*.

**Example:**

```
------ Main thread ------
1. Index is 0            |----------- Thread 1 ------------|
2. Thread 1 is created   |                                 |
3. Index is 1            |                                 |---------- Thread 2 -----------
4. Thread 2 is created   |   Thread 1 reads index 1 here   |
5. Index is 2            |                                 |  Thread 2 reads index 2 here
6. Thread 3 is created   |                                 |
...
```

One way to solve this is to simply let the lambda capture `icpu` by **value** instead (make a copy).

```
t[icpu] = std::thread([&, icpu] { test[icpu] = myf(startIndex, endIndex); });
```

<kbd>[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff3baefe0695862d)</kbd>

<sub>† Remember that the thread execution order is scheduled by the operating system.</sub>

Comment: Thanks Snps for such an elaborate explanation and also thank you for editing my code. Now the code is more readable.

Comment: @musafir Glad to help! You can award the efforts of others on Stack Overflow by upvoting their answers and accepting the most qualified answer.